# C# Search item and return in Listview

Tags: c#, .net, listview, listbox

I have some question about Listview in C#
My listview contains with 2 column like this :

```
colDATA1          colDATA2
 Value1            Amount1
 Value2            Amount2
 Value3            Amount3
 Value4            Amount4
```

And what I am trying to make is search `Amount5` in Listview If not exist then do something.And if exist then return the `Value5`

I am trying to search and use the code like this :

```
If (Listview1.items.containskey("Amount5"))
{}
else
{MessageBox.show("Not Found")}

or if exist then return the value5 *I have no idea how to do.
```

I am searching this in google but most of it have only 1 Column and when I use the code the code won't work.

```
My question is :
 1. How can I get Value5 if Amount5 exist.
```

Thank you.

The code to add the items

```
First Set listView1 Property "View : Details" Then Using this code
this.Listview1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { Value1, Amount1 }));
```

Comment: Neither of your questions are actually questions, so it is not clear what you are playing at.  In a case where you need search or filter capabilities, a DataGridView makes more sense (as well as acting on the *data* rather than a control).  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @Plutonix What? I am using ListView and you asking me to use DataGridview? I think that is not how to solved the problem.

Comment: @plutonix And I think that you didn't read my problem clearly, In my ListView not containing Amount5 and Value5. So I ask how to retrieving their data if exist.

Comment: Are you binding an object to each row in the ListViwe? if yes then you will search on items foreach(yourObject item in Listview1.items) if(item.amount == amount5){ MessageBox.Show(item.value)}

Comment: Fun fact: the ListView is not a grid control and doesnt store typed data.  That makes it very ill suited for this sort of thing.  You apparently missed the point working with the data is always a better idea than fishing it out of a control.  Also your post and comment are complaining about 2 different things potentially.  The post talks about `ContainsKey` not working but the comment says `my ListView not containing Amount5`.  Those are 2 different things. You didnt show how Items were added so we'd have to guess at a solution.  Read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @user3382285 Yes sir. Now its work thaks alot.

Comment: @Plutonix I don't know that why are you always rushing to the end of the question. I have already mention that "*I have no idea how to do."
And also I didn't say that Containskey not working. I've say that "I am searching this in google but most of it have only 1 Column and when I use the code the code won't work." == I don't know that its only work for 1 column or not. Or I thinks that my English is bad so I can't explain to you to understand. Sorry

Comment: @ArGOO Please if you found my answer useful mark it as the answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP already figured it out but this is just for future reference in case someone needs it.

What OP was missing is that ListView holds its items as objects in the Items property.

```
If (Listview1.items.containskey("Amount5"))
{}
else
{MessageBox.show("Not Found")}
```

containsKey is usually in dictionaries-like data structures. However, a ListView controller's Items is ItemCollection (for dictionaries you can use a DataGrid)

In your case I would do this using Linq.

```
 // Returns the first item that satisfies the condition or null if none does.
        ListViewItem found = items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.SubItems[1].Text.Equals("Amount5"));

        if(found != null) {

            MessageBox.Show(found.SubItems[0].Text.ToString());
        }
        else {

            MessageBox.Show("Not Found!");

        }
```

You can still use a for loop to do the same thing too.

If I want to use a foreach loop (since Linq can't be directly used on ListView.Item)

```
      ListViewItem found = null;

        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items) {

            if (item.SubItems[1].Text.Equals("Amount5")) {

                // If a match was found break the loop.
                found = item;
                break;
            }

        }

        if (found != null) {

            MessageBox.Show(found.SubItems[0].Text.ToString());
        }
        else {

            MessageBox.Show("Not Found!");

        }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What do I have to declare array to ? When I use this code its says no Array in the project. Thank for answer

Comment: "array" is just the variable name.In your question, I saw that you are passing a new string array to the constructor of ListViewItem (this.Listview1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { Value1, Amount1 }));).  Use variable in the ListViewItem object that holds the new string [] you passed.

Comment: Err . Sorry did you mean columnName?

Comment: No, I mean the name of the string[] property in your ListViewItem class. You are looping on Listview1.Items which are ListViewItem objects. In your ListViewItem, do you have a property string[] defined? If you still have issues with this, show me your ListViewItem code.

Comment: No. I don't have any property define. I just created the Listview then add the code. Sorry I am newbie.

Comment: I just only add the ListView to have 2 column

Comment: Ok I think I figured out the problem it was my bad. In C# forms the object ListViewItem is already there. So it access the element of the array use  if (item.SubItems[1].Text.Equals("Amount5")). I am more used to wpf now and that was my bad I am sorry.

Comment: yes. But I don't want to use (item.SubItems[1].Text.Equals("Amount5")) for any time that I want to find the items because of I don't know where will Subitems be. How can I use Loop through all of subitems?

Comment: How I have to change this "MessageBox.Show(found.item[0]);"

Comment: I have already try to use Changed Code. But its always say Not Found:(

Comment: if you wanna loop through the SubItems it's a collection so you can use  2 for loops like 
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items) {

              foreach(ListViewSubItem subItem in item.SubItems) {
....}}

Comment: since it's returning "Not Found" that means the string value is not the same make sure the If statement has the correct condition.

Comment: You are welcome. I recommend that you read more about objects and how to access their properties. Also take a look at this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem(v=vs.110).aspx it has alot of information about ListView. Good Luck!

Comment: Can I ask more?, If I want to change from (item.SubItems[1].Text.Equals("Amount5")) to ListView2.items.contains(item.SubItems[1].Text). means checking that Listview1 are in Listview2 or not. Can it be done?

Comment: I would say this is a new question, so it's better to create a new question for that so others and I can help you more and other people can search for this new question in the future.

Comment: I can't create more question till 4 days. because of at first my question have been downvote.

Comment: you can use it but contains is not the right function since contains looks for ListViewItem and if you create 2 objects of ListViewItem with the same values (let's say ( amont5, value5 )) that doesn't mean they are the same object so this function will returns false.... What you want to check is subItem.Text from the first ViewList == subItem.Text from the second ViewList. Maybe there's a better way but I am not aware of it.